# How to change MSAA settings after creating the swap chain D3D11

Tags: directx-11, direct3d, dxgi

Before i create the device and swap chain using D3D11CreateDeviceAndSwapChain,
i have to fill out the DXGI_SWAP_CHAIN_DESC structure.

There is a function that returns the highest quality level supported for "X" sample count.
But It Is a part of the device interface, And i create the device after i can set the MSAA settings.
Is there a way to set the MSAA after D3D11CreateDeviceAndSwapChain?

Comment: Make 3 calls: `D3D11CreateDevice` (get info you want), `CreateDXGIFactoryX` and call one of `IDXGIFactory::CreateSwapChainXXX` methods